# How to use composite key with join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these tables:

`ACCOUNTS`:

| BANK_ID (PK) | BRANCH_ID (PK) | ACCOUNT_NUM (PK) | CURRENCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 621 | 1001 | ILS |
| 20 | 623 | 1002 | USD |
| 20 | 90 | 1003 | GBP |

`AMOUNTS`:

| ACCOUNT_REC (PK) | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 20 621 1001 | 10000 |
| 20 623 1002 | 20000 |
| 20 90 1003 | 30000 |

I need to get the data in this form:

| BANK_ID | BRANCH_ID | ACCOUNT_NUM | CURRENCY | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 621 | 1001 | ILS | 10000 |
| 20 | 623 | 1002 | USD | 20000 |
| 20 | 90 | 1003 | GBP | 30000 |

Any idea for that?

Comment: I would, personally, suggest you split the column in the second table, or add a computed column with the value concatenated in the first and `INDEX` what ever solution you choose to use appropriately. Then you can use a SARGable solution.

Comment: Sql Server is a *relational* database. It is designed to relate information stored in tables. There are many benefits of structuring your tables appropriately such as having fast retrieval, easily updateable, constraining the data to what should be allowed, readability, just to name the most common ones. Your 1st table does a good job at this (on first glance). With your structure now you have to parse out the values and then try to relate them. There are also no hard guarantees that the FK values even exist in the related tables in your current structure.

Comment: That's not a composite key, that's a bad design that violates the most basic database rule (1st Normal Form) - one field, one value. It can't be indexed, queried and hence used in JOINs in a meaningful way. Composite Primary Keys by definition are those that are have multiple columns in the constraint clause. You don't have to do anything special to use them in JOINs, just specify the fields in the `ON` clause

Comment: PS: SQL Server 2008 is years past its End Of Life. The oldest version still in mainstream support in SQL Server 2019. You could split the values in `ACCOUNT_REC` with the STRING_SPLIT function first introduced in SQL Server 2017 but the order of the results isn't guaranteed. That option was added in SQL Server 2022.

Answer (score -1):

Just do that:

```
SELECT 
  ac.*, am.amount 
FROM 
  ACCOUNTS ac
    JOIN AMOUNTS am ON 
      am.account_rec = CONCAT(bank_id, ' ', branch_id, ' ', account_num);
```